# Resume: how to best sort skills according to proficiency

Tags: resume, applications

In my CV, where I state my skills (e.g. programming languages, software etc.) I also want to add my proficiency level (beginner, advanced, expert or something like that). Also I want to design them in 3 columns.

Does it look better if I have more skills listed under 'expert' or under 'beginner' or is it best to have everywhere the same amount of skills.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it.

I've seen people use star ratings and other numbering schemes, but these are pointless since they're so subjective.

I know that you're a graphic designer, but you should really keep your resume layout simple for computers. Many times, you'll have to cut and paste the text of your resume into a web form, and at other times, your resume will be scanned and OCR will be used to deciper what it says.

Comment: Aye. Whenever I see "Expert - [Skill I've spent 10 years mastering]", my first thought is always 'yeah, we'll see about that'.

Comment: Everything Stephan says is totally correct (1) completely forget the 3-column idea (2) it's a fact that ***the resumes of graphic designers should be as ridiculously boring plain text as anyone else***.  this comes up often on this site and has been covered many times.  completely forget the idea of a "designy" resume.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't care about your 'skills.'"  I can quickly show you what you need to know to work at my place of business.  Of far more importance to me is your *human* skills:  how well you work with a team, are you a "lone wolf," will you take direction, attention to detail, leaves politics at home, and so on.